# Tranfering Music and videos from pc to phone

Tags: zune, 7.5

I have bought a new Nokia Lumia 510 and installed Zune software on my PC. But I am unable to transfer music and videos from PC to phone. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: installed zune..  trying to drag items over the hovered mobile button in the left bottom.. but nothing is happaneing

Comment: plz i want zune software and nokia lumia 510 software plz send my mail

Answer (score 4):

at the top, there is a collections tab; this represents media on your computer. These map to your libraries in Windows. It is from -here- that you drag and drop to the phone in the bottom left corner, not from windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Select music tab in collection, right click on any file, select the option sync with your phone's name (e.g. SYNC WITH LUMIA 510).

Check the bottom left corner and see whether the %1 has started or not.

Comment: Sorry, what does "%1" mean?